# Android P, Total Silence

Tags: settings, mute, 9.0-pie

I installed Android P once it got released for Google Pixel phone. But they changed how you mute your phone. Now there is the option to put your device on vibrate/mute on the bar that appears when you change the volume and then there is the "do not disturb" option.

In Android 8 you had as option to change the "do not disturb" option to "total silence". How do you recreate this?

When you have "do not disturb" on stuff like YouTube, it still plays sounds; same for the Whatsapp message sound. Muting on that bar thingy still lets calls through and both together *seem* to work out but i cant be sure. I don't want my phone to go off in meetings so I hope someone can give me some insights.

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Google has removed this feature in Android P. There is a feature request open here -> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80089859

You can go and Star that ticket to show your support for it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i already thought noone understands my problem

Comment: We all feel the pain. Android P DND is a disaster, 10 steps backwards! Google decided to simplify DND but I think they have over simplified and made a dumb useless DND. Just go ahead and "Star" that open ticket. Also spread the word about this feature request under relevant forums. Hopefully we can get our voice heard.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit the volume buttons you should see a bell icon, press it and it goes to vibrate, press it again and it's silent, at least that's what it does on my phone

Comment: thats what i already descripted.... the problem is in silent mode calls still make noice